# How can I update a column with PL\SQL by using a calculated value

Tags: oracle, plsql, sql-update, cursor

I created a dummy database for learning purposes, and I purposefully created some duplicated records in one of the tables. In every case I want to flag one of the duplicated records as Latest='Y', and the other record as 'N', and for every single record the Latest flag would be 'Y'.

I tried to use PlSQL to go through all of my records, but when I try to use the previously calculated value (which would tell that its a duplicated record) it says that:

ORA-06550: line 20, column 17:
PLS-00201: identifier 'COUNTER' must be declared

Here is the statement I try to use:

`DECLARE
    CURSOR cur
    IS
        SELECT order_id, order_date, person_id, 
               amount, successfull_order, country_id, latest, ROWCOUNT AS COUNTER
                  FROM (SELECT order_id,
                               order_date,
                               person_id,
                               amount,
                               successfull_order,
                               country_id,
                               latest,
                               ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY order_id, order_date, 
                                     person_id, amount, successfull_order, country_id
                                         ORDER BY order_id, order_date, 
                            person_id, amount, successfull_order, country_id) ROWCOUNT
                          FROM orders) orders
        FOR UPDATE OF orders.latest;
    rec   cur%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    FOR rec IN cur
    LOOP
        IF MOD (COUNTER, 2) = 0
        THEN
            UPDATE orders
               SET latest = 'N'
             WHERE CURRENT OF cur;
        ELSE
            UPDATE orders
               SET latest = 'Y'
             WHERE CURRENT OF cur;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
END;`

I am new to PlSQL so I tried to modify the statements I found here:
http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/plsql/cursors/for_update.html

What should I change in my statement, or should I use a different approach?

Thanks for your answers in advance!
Botond

Comment: you should be accessing it from the cursor reference like `MOD (rec.COUNTER, 2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your refer the `ROWNUM` as `COUNTER` in your cursor.
While fetching, you should be accessing it from the cursor reference like `MOD (rec.COUNTER, 2)`

Comment: Thanks, for the answer but that way I've got a new issue. It does not want to update because I use partition over by. I used a workaround instead of this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the variable COUNTER and then you need to maintain (ie increment) it in your loop. 
I suspect that you example is just for learning PL/SQL. However be aware that it's often much more performant to do things with a single SQL statement, as opposed to using cursor loops.

Comment: Thanks I used a workaround, by creating an entirely new table with some helper columns. This way I did not have to use PLSQL.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that `COUNTER` is an attribute of the cursor record `rec` and not a PL/SQL variable. So:

```
IF MOD (COUNTER, 2) = 0
```

Should be:

```
IF MOD (rec.COUNTER, 2) = 0
```

However, you do not need to use PL/SQL or cursors, it can be done in a single `MERGE` statement:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE orders ( order_id, order_date, latest ) AS
SELECT 1, DATE '2017-01-01', CAST( NULL AS CHAR(1) ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2017-01-02', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2017-01-03', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2017-01-04', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2017-01-01', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, DATE '2017-01-06', NULL FROM DUAL;
```

**Update Statement**:

```
MERGE INTO orders dst
USING ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY order_id
                                   ORDER BY order_date DESC ) AS rn
        FROM   orders
      ) src
ON ( src.ROWID = dst.ROWID )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET latest = CASE src.rn WHEN 1 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END;
```

**Output**:

```
SELECT * FROM orders;

ORDER_ID ORDER_DATE LATEST
-------- ---------- ------
       1 2017-01-01 N
       1 2017-01-02 N
       1 2017-01-03 Y
       2 2017-01-04 Y
       2 2017-01-01 N
       3 2017-01-06 Y
```